# Strong Triadic Closure and Nodes that Violate/satisfy it

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I am very confused about Strong Triadic Closure and knowing what nodes satisfy and violate it. I know 100%,, if it does NOT violate, then it satisfies it.

If there are 3 nodes, and Node A is connected to B and C, but B and C are not connected, then that violates it. But I guess I am stuck since mine is a larger Diagram.

Do B and C violate since they are not connected and do not allow a triangle to be formed? And do the rest of the nodes satisfy it? I added the diagram below. I feel stupid for asking such a simple question, but I am all messed up on it[image]

Thanks guys!

EDIT: after looking at it for hours, I feel that F and E violate STC, hmmm

Answer (score 1):

Yes as in the previous answer they told you that it's B,E and F.
I can say yes but let consider E for now; you see, E has many bridges: to F, C, D and G.
as E is having strong ties with B and D, and the fact that there is no edge between B and D, in that case E violate the STC rule.

But you can also find that in the other case, E fulfills the STC rule, where there  are strong ties between (E and F) and between (E and B) and a weak tie between (F and B)!!

Answer (score 0):

The nodes that violate the strong triadic closure property are B,E, and F